# Como faço para executar uma função main() sem afetar a outra de um outro script?

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Tenho três arquivos:

Arquivo1.js

```
function main() {
    . . .
}
```

Arquivo2.js

```
function main() {
    . . .
}
```

System.js

```
function openApp(package) {
    var a = document.createElement("script");
    a.src = "/" + package + "/Arquivo1.js";
    document.body[0].appendChild(a);
}
```

Como faço para chamar a `main()` do Arquivo1 sem afetar a `main()` do Arquivo2 dentro do arquivo System, que é a cabeça...

Já escrevi esse post no stackoverflow original, mas ninguém respondeu...

EDIT: atualizei o código, quero que fique padronizado tudo!

Answer (score 0):

Uma saída é não poluir o namespace global, encapsulando as funções de cada arquivo em um protótipo. Nesse caso, o `Arquivo1`se torna:

Arquivo1.js

```
function Arquivo1() {
    this.main = function() {
        return 'A1'
    }
}
```

Analogamente para o `Arquivo2`. Agora as funções estão isoladas, cada uma em seu próprio protótipo. Agora, no arquivo principal, podemos fazer:

System.js

```
arquivo1 = new Arquivo1()
arquivo2 = new Arquivo2()
valorDaMainDoArquivo1 = Arquivo1.main()
valorDaMainDoArquivo2 = Arquivo2.main()
```

Comment: E como eu faço isso eum um sistema de packages, identico ao android, bem, eu tenho uma funçao que registra os javascripts por pastas, se o package for "a.a.a", a pasta sera a.a.a/js/main.js, e teria que ser padrão para todos os arquivos, pois o system está dentro de uma função...

Comment: Então nesse caso eu teria que escrever package + Arquivo1.main?

Comment: Bom, creio que eu entendi o seu problema corretamente. O System é responsável por adicionar as funções ao arquivo html e você acessa essas funções posteriormente, correto?

Comment: Sim, exato.....

Comment: Bom, nesse caso eu te recomendaria a usar módulos: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/modules#browser, ou então utilizar um bundler para compilar todo o seu código em um arquivo só, como o Webpack https://webpack.js.org/